# Woo-commerce Composite Products in one line?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I don't know style my composite product components into one line?It seems they're all separate div's.

Like this : https://www.exit82art.com/shop/selena-fara/pretty-things

My site : https://exit82artstore.blackbearweb.us/product/pretty-things/

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achive? To make the components like (STONE DRINK COASTER, NEOPRENE COASTER) into a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce can be quite confusing since the templates are deeply nested and not always that spelling. So there are two ways to achieve what you want.

### 1. Overwrite the Woocommerce templates

The first thing you could do is simply overwriting the `PHP` template for this partial. In this case, you would gain control of the markup and you could customize it according to your needs.

Check out the docs about custom templates to pick the one you need: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

### 2. Pure CSS approach (recommended)

If you don't want to maintain custom templates in the future, you can also achieve the exact same thing with pure `CSS`. Simply use `flex`.

```
.composite_form .component {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.composite_form .step_title_wrapper {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.component_wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.component_wrap .price {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

> be aware of the browser support of `flex`: https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I truly wanted. I did add the pure css through my theme customizer and worked like you said. exit82artstore.blackbearweb.us/product/pretty-things But, I can't get two of the components to line up correctly, and I tinker with the values, but I'm unsuccessful.